# Symfony3 ( or htaccess) enforce HTTPS on specific base url only

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, ssl

- I have the same Symfony3 code base running on 2 servers (urls).
- Both use the PROD environment and DEV environment gets used by myself for debugging.
- The one has an SSL certificate and requires all routes to be forced to the https scheme. The other does not and requires the normal http scheme.
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/force_https.html explains how to force all routes to https via security.yml

**Is there a way that I can implement it so that the https scheme is enforced for base url A but not for base url B, other than maintaining two separate security.yml files?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^prod.yourdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Now only prod.yourdomain.com will be redirected to https.